# Is there another way to say, "drive the point in further?" or belabor the point?"

Tags: phrases, expressions, british-english, metaphors, analogy

In a work I am writing, two characters are having a discussion that becomes quite heated. The man makes an observation about the woman that is less than flattering and then while she's still recovering, frames it another way, as if to drive the point in further.

I wonder if there is another expression or phrase or analogy that describes this better. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**harp away at** (someone or something) or **harp on**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/harp) idioms

> To complain about or dwell upon someone or something repeatedly and to
>   the point of tediousness.

As in:

*The man makes an observation about the woman that is less than flattering, then **harps on** with further derogatory comments.*

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

“Add insult to injury”—commonly defined as making a bad situation worse.

Comment: please provide a source

Comment: And please explain how this addresses the Q.. To me, “Add insult to injury” is completely different from "belaboring a point".